# How can a user enter 10 elements in an array defined for 100 elements?

Tags: c

Here, I want to take input from the user in an array. The condition is the array size should not exceed 100 elements. But, if the user has only 10 elements as input, what can he do? Because he will not be able to stop the loop after 10 elements as I have defined it for 100.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int* A;
    int i;

    A = (int*)malloc(100*(sizeof(A)));

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will have to define a stop condition. Think from the user perspective - what should they do to let the program know that they are done?

Comment: You should *always* check what [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) *returns*.

Comment: A while loop is more appropriate here. Add a condition to not exceed 100 and another to break if the user has less than 100.

Comment: `A = (int*)malloc(100*(sizeof(A)));` ==> `A = malloc(100 * sizeof *A);` -- the size of a pointer is not necessarily the same as the size of a `int`.

Comment: @pmg Why not `int A[100];` instead?

Comment: @ChinmayKhole Using `sizeof` on a pointer (like you do with `sizeof(A)`) is almost *never* correct. It gives you the size of the *pointer* and not what it might point to. And `sizeof A` doesn't have to be equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: correcting the sizeof is less of a change than changing the type. I wanted to change as little as possible. If I were to make big changes, I would consider `A[100]` :)

Comment: There was another thought in my mind which i haven't written here. Why allocate memory for 100 elements if the user only needs 10? That's why I wrote it for dynamic allocation. Many things in mind which I can't express here.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways to do this. Here are two potential options:

- First, you could add a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) that the user enters to stop input, such as a negative number, zero, or a non-number. Then check the input and break if you encounter your sentinel value.
- Secondly, have the user enter the number of values they wish to enter first, and make that the ending condition of your for loop. `for(i=0; i != num_entries && i<100; i++)`

Comment: Thirdly, recognize when the user is "inputting" the end-of-file sequence (`Ctrl-Z` or `Ctrl-D`, depending on OS) and use that as the end for the loop.

Comment: While forcing the user to enter the count in advance may be easiest for the programmer, it's worst for the user.  If you care about human factors and the user experience, never do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be some way for the user to tell the program that he's done inputting values.

You could have the user first enter the number of values he wants to read:

```
int count;
printf("Number of values: ");
int rval = scanf("%d", &count);

if (rval == 1) {
    for(i=0; i<count && i<100; i++) {
        rval = scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        if (!rval) {
            int c;
            while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && (c != EOF));
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could have the user enter values continuously until a special value is entered:

```
printf("Enter values (enter -1 to stop): ");
for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
    int value;
    int rval = scanf("%d", &value);
    if (!rval) {
        int c;
        while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && (c != EOF));
    } else if (value != -1) {
        A[i] = value;
    } else {
        // -1 was entered
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int* A;
    int i;

    A = (int*)malloc(100*(sizeof(*A)));

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        int numEl = scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        if(numEl!=1) break;
    }
    free(A);
    printf("Read %d values\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Just break if you found anything, but a number:

```
gcc q.c && ./a.out 
1
2
3



4
end
Read 4 values
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char  opp="";
int i=0;
while(opp!="*")
{
    printf("Enter element %d :",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
    // You code here
   printf("press * to stop:");
   opp=getch();
   i++;
   if (i>=100)
    break;

}
```

Try this .. Until  the user input *  it will keep on asking to input

Comment: so little code ... so many errors!! line 1: assigning a string ie an array ie a pointer to a char; line comparing a char to a string; line of `getch()`: losing `EOF`, always assigning `\n` from the last `scanf()` to opp and possibly leaving the `*` for `scanf()` to catch and give error which you don´t even try to notice.